# Front end developer trying to understand weird syntax in Wordpress/PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a front end designer starting to dabble in backend stuff.

I am starting to create a wordpress site for a side business of mine and am using a couple of different plugins. In order for me to successfully use this plugin, I have to edit one of the plugins template files. When I use a certain option in the plugin (Pulling a image down from amazon, tumblr, ebay, instagram, etc...), it pulls down the correct image but inserts a hard coded width and height in the html.

This is great for rendering of the page quick, but I want to change the width and height of the image in the html.

Here's the kicker. In the php, there is a template file in the plugin where i see it pulls this from. It's 50% regular html code and 50% php in the template file.

(So in the plugin settings, if you choose this option, it pulls from that image template.)

In the template, there is a section for the image tag. Which places the `<img xxxxxx src=xxxx width=xxxxx height=xxxxx alt=xxxxxx>` code into the html.

Here is how the code reads.

```
    <?php
/*
 * Template:    Image and Prices
 * Stylesheets: basic.css, image.css
 * Scripts:     popover.js
 */
?>

<?php
$price_l = isset($item['attributes']['ListPrice']) ? $item['attributes']['ListPrice'] : false;
$price_c = isset($item['offer']) && isset($item['offer']['price']) ? $item['offer']['price'] : false;
$price_l_numeric = floatval(preg_replace('#[^\d.]#', '', $price_l));
$price_c_numeric = floatval(preg_replace('#[^\d.]#', '', $price_c));
?>

<div class="easyazon-block-information">
    <?php if($image_atts) { ?>
    <div class="easyazon-block-image-container">
        <?php printf('<a %s><img %s /></a>', easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), easyazon_collapse_attributes($image_atts)); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="easyazon-block-information-title"><?php printf('<a %s>%s</a>', easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), esc_html($item['title'])); ?></div>

    <div class="easyazon-block-information-prices">
        <?php if($price_l && (false === $price_c || $price_l_numeric >= $price_c_numeric)) { ?>
        <div class="easyazon-block-information-price"><?php printf('<td class="easyazon-block-information-price-label">%s:</td> <td class="easyazon-block-information-price-value"><a %s>%s</a></td>', __('List Price'), easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), esc_html($price_l)); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($price_c && 'N/A' !== $price_c) { ?>
        <div class="easyazon-block-information-price"><?php printf('<td class="easyazon-block-information-price-label">%s:</td> <td class="easyazon-block-information-price-value"><a %s>%s</a></td>', __('Price'), easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), esc_html($price_c)); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if($item['offer'] && $item['offer']['saved'] && 'N/A' !== $item['offer']['saved']) { ?>
        <div class="easyazon-block-information-price"><?php printf('<td class="easyazon-block-information-price-label">%s:</td> <td class="easyazon-block-information-price-value"><a %s>%s</a></td>', __('You Save'), easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), esc_html($item['offer']['saved'])); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php if($cta_atts) { ?>
    <div class="easyazon-block-information-cta">
        <?php $cta_atts['class'][] = 'easyazon-block-cta'; ?>
        <?php printf('<a %s><img %s /></a>', easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), easyazon_collapse_attributes($cta_atts)); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="easyazon-block-information-price-disclaimer">
        <small class="easyazon-price-disclaimer" data-content="<?php printf(__('Prices are accurate as of %1$s. Product prices and availability are subject to change. Any price and availablility information displayed on Amazon at the time of purchase will apply to the purchase of any products.'), date('F j, Y \a\t g:i A', $item['fetched'] + get_option('gmt_offset') * HOUR_IN_SECONDS)); ?>"><?php _e('Price Disclaimer'); ?></small>
    </div>
</div>
```

What does the s% mean? How does this code pull in all this information for the image. Is it located somewhere else in the plugin? There's lots of other folder. I couldn't personally find it, maybe I didn't look hard enough?

Comment: Sorry the code didnt post. It says <img s%>

Comment: Is this wrapped under <?php tag ?

Comment: Can you provide some more information, like the name of the plugin, or the contents of the template file in question?

Comment: No Problem! The name of the plugin is easyazon. I am trying to create an affilaite site, but can't manage to change the size of the image it uses. here is the code of the image block. I edited the original post.

Comment: the %s is everywhere. here is another example. 
    <?php printf('<strong>%s:</strong> <a %s>%s</a>', __('List Price'), easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), esc_html($price_l)); ?>
 </div>

I can't figure out how this %s is pulling information in. all i want to be able to do it change the size of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` is a type specifier which means it will treat it as a string.
It uses the format argument with these specifies that act as slots that the following arguments will be slotted into.

`$format = 'some digit %d and some string %s';
echo sprintf($format, $digit, $string);`

Comment: I understand now that %d and %s are for digits and strings. So using img %s pull in the string with the attributes of the image. Are these strings something that is hard coded from somewhere else in the plugin or are these values that are being populated from amazon? There has to be a way to change what size the plugin is writing for with the width and height attributes in the html code. Just want to make the image bigger. Hmm.

Comment: The strings are slots for the arguments that are passed in to the rest of the printf function. So  for `       <?php printf('<a %s><img %s /></a>', easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts), easyazon_collapse_attributes($image_atts)); ?>` the first `%s` is replaced with the value of `easyazon_collapse_attributes($link_atts)` and the second is replaced with the value of `easyazon_collapse_attributes($image_atts));`

Comment: ahhh that makes sense now, thank you PeaceBringer I appreciate that!